# Javascript closure, calling function different ways

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm able to call this closure as so:

```
var increment = (function () {
  var test = 0;

  return function () {
    test++;
    console.log(test);

  }

})();
increment(); //1
increment(); //2
```

However how do I call this using regular function syntax?

```
function increment() {
   var test = 0;

   return function () {
     test++;
     console.log(test);
   }
}
increment()(); 1
increment()(); 1
```

Comment: Whenever you call `increment()` you create a "new counter", so the second example is not the same, you're creating 2 different instances.

Comment: So is there a way to call using the second way?  I'm calling it from a onclick event.

Comment: Yes, just call `var inc = increment()` then use `inc()` to increment the counter.

Comment: They're both "regular function syntax". Do you understand how the `increment` function works?

Comment: though, then it's really not much different than an immediately invoked anonymous function... I'm not really sure what problem the OP is trying to circumvent...

Comment: My problem of trying stupid things for no reason at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you call `increment()` you create a "new counter", so the second example is not the same, you're creating 2 different instances.

You'd have to create an instance first, then use that:

```
var inc = increment();

inc(); // 1
inc(); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a function so it would be

```
var inc = increment();
inc();
inc();
```

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/hLQ3x/